# Synchronizing my records between two separate databases

Tags: asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

I am building a BPM based on asp.net MVC, I am working on two systems:-

1. A third party BPM.
2. My own BPM system.

Currently when I am adding a new process I am doing the following:-

1. Create new process at the third party application using its REST API.
2. Create a new process at my own BPM database.

But I am facing the following problems:-

1. How I can add/edit/delete the records from the two systems is a consistence manner, so if the record was not added in the third party system I have to remove it from my system, and visa versa.

My Process model class is:-

```
public class newprocess
    {

        public string name { get; set; }
        public string activityId { get; set; } 
     public string Status {get; set;}
    }
```

My action method is:-

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult CreateProcess(string name) {
using (var client = new WebClient())
{
try
{
repository.CreateProcess(name,"Pending");
repository.save();

var query = HttpUtility.ParseQueryString(string.Empty);
query["j_username"] = "kermit";
query["hash"] = "9449B5ABCFA9AFDA36B801351ED3DF66";
query["loginAs"] = User.Identity.Name;
var url = new UriBuilder("http://localhost:8080/jw/web/json/Process/create/" + name.ToString() );
url.Query = query.ToString();
string json = client.DownloadString(url.ToString());
var serializer = new JavaScriptSerializer();
var myObject = serializer.Deserialize<newprocess>(json);
string activityid = myObject.activityId;

if (activityid != null)
{
repository.UpdateProcess(name, "Finish");
repository.save();
}
```

So what I am doing inside my POST action method, is :-

1. Create a new record at my database with a status of “pending”.
2. Calling the third Party API, and get the result.
3. If the ActivityID is not null (the create successes in the third party system), I am updating my record status to be “finish”. Else the status will stay pending.
4. I have built a screen which display all the records with the status “pending” , and the admin will be able to delete them from my own database.

So will my approach work well , or it will create problems I am unaware of . Or should I be looking for a completely different approach

thanks in advance for any help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The direction looks ok. But remember to complete the cycle and consider a few more options

Based on your statement **"what I am doing"**

> 1   Create a new record at my database with a status of “pending”.
>
> 2   Calling the third Party API, and get the result.
>
> 3   If the ActivityID is not null (the create successes in the third party system), I am updating my record status to be “finish”. Else the status will stay pending.
>
> 4   I have built a screen which display all the records with the status “pending” , and the admin will be able to delete them from my own database.

You have covered the main concept of 2 staged commit. And If all goes well this will be fine.
But you should also consider.

1. Investigate if only from a theory point of view "reliable messaging".
   May be overkill here.

   1. What if you dont receive a reply. You cant assume it wasnt posted.
      The return traffic may get lost post commit on the other side.
      So you should follow up with check exists calls or manually tidy up.You actually need to posting your sides entry rather than deleting it everytime there is not response.  Delete of course is the most likely. Of course im not talking about your side receives the message NOT posted. That is a clear known state.
2. What happens if your pending to finished change commit fails?
   How do you recover this situation.
   Delete the otherside entry?   or retry yourside.
3. You should also consider what the basic pattern/plan is when the other side is not reachable at all. Accept the posts, record many as pending and have a process that retries the pending records later. Or just fail all new calls until the other party is reachable.
   At least think about the non perfect world scenarios and have a plan.

That is the basic pattern.  And doing some of it manually is ok. It is a plan and is a valid pattern.
Of course you can add tools, and logic to help support this. 
eg error handling, automated retry patterns.  Asynchronous acknowledgements etc.
But that is taking it to enterprise level. At an enterprise cost.

Basically If you take the stance ONE system is responsible for the overall integrity and ongoing synchronization. That is the best place to start. You have that. Your system is the Orchestrator and responsible for synchronization outcomes.